# add a parameter to a soap call in php

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm fairly new to soap calls but I have got a simple one working ok, using arrays.

```
$xml_array['searchName'] = "websvc";
$xml_Parray['name'] = "Cust Code";
$xml_Parray['value'] = "338877";
//   $Parray['searchParameter xsi:type="met:StringParameter"']=$xml_Parray;     //errors 
$Parray['searchParameter']=$xml_Parray;


$client = new WSSoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0));
$client->__setUsernameToken($UserName, $Password);
$client->__setLocation('http://127.0.0.1:80/demo/search');          

$xml_array['searchParameters'] = $Parray;

$response = $client->__soapCall("getDocuments", array($xml_array));
```

So this give me...

```
<searchName>websvc</searchName>
<searchParameters>
  <searchParameter>
    <name>Cust Code</name>
    <value>338877</value>
  </searchParameter>
</searchParameters>
```

BUT I now need to add additional text

xsi:type="met:StringParameter"

```
<searchName>websvc</searchName>
<searchParameters>
  <searchParameter xsi:type="met:StringParameter">
    <name>Cust Code</name>
    <value>338877</value>
  </searchParameter>
</searchParameters>
```

I simply tried

```
$Parray['searchParameter xsi:type="met:StringParameter"']=$xml_Parray;
```

but get a reponse

Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'searchParameter' property

Can anyone help ?

Update. I have found out that what i am trying to do is add attributes!

So I have tried this

```
array("searchParameter" => array("_" => "$xml_Parray", "xsi:type"=>"met:StringParameter"));
```

But I'm not sure thats right either!

Comment: You cannot change the WSDL from the client end. You have to change the WSDL from the server end to allow the client to use the new field

Comment: HI, it has been added at the server end, now I need to code for it

Comment: When the server changes, so should have the `wsdl` defintion. Are you using an outdated one?

Comment: according to the developers of the server end, the wsdl is correct, though I do have my doubts!

Comment: Ignoring the fact that I am getting the error, does anyone know how to add the attributes in php. I've found some info that I should be using simpleXML to do this ?